# php - Warning: filter_var() [function.filter-var]: Unknown modifier '+'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html, specifically:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

However when using this along with:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>$pattern)))
```

It brings up the error:

```
Warning: filter_var() [function.filter-var]: Unknown modifier '+'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is your pattern surrounded by delimiters and have you escaped everything correctly? E.g. `$pattern = "/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i";`

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for the help Dave, it obviously hadn't included delimiters.If I'm honest I don't know anything about regular expressions, I need to read up.

Answer (score 5):

Your regexp is missing delimiters. Inserting, say, a semicolon before and after the pattern will fix this.

However, you should really **use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`** instead of rolling out your own ([incorrect](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)) regexp.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL has it's problems and isn't perfect, I'm not looking for a perfect solution just one that hit's the majority and I just wanted to test this one (I didn't make it).I will probably just use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, but I plan to make single quotes invalidate the email, whether or not the RFC says they're legal.

Comment: @Alex What problems are you speaking about? Have considered filing a bug against php to get these problems removed? And why do you use your own definition of what consists a legal email address?